# Bukkit Event If-Statement being ignored

Tags: java, if-statement, bukkit

I am working on a 'Building Mode' for a Minecraft Server and I am really confused in one part. The Build Mode works fine, however when the event is being triggered, it behaves in a way that the checks 'work' when the player is op.

Here is the event:

```
@EventHandler
public void blockBreakWithBuilder(BlockBreakEvent e)
{
    if (onWorld(e.getPlayer()) && !e.getPlayer().isOp() || !buildMode.hasBuildMode(e.getPlayer()))
    {
        e.getPlayer().sendMessage("True");
        e.setCancelled(blockBreak);
        return;
    }

    e.getPlayer().sendMessage("False");
}
```

It should check if the player is op, or if the player is on build mode. If true, the event should not be cancelled thus let the player break blocks.

It only works when the player is an Operator which makes it really difficult to track down the problem.

Related Method:

```
public boolean hasBuildMode(Player player)
{
    return builders.contains(player);
}
```

**How do I check if the player is a builder/Operator and not cancel the event?**

Comment: @FredLarson Put that as an answer, as it is

Comment: May be because of preference, but why are you using `return` in your if-statement, continuing with more commands, while you can use `else` without `return`.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading this right, your code doesn't match your statement of what you want to happen. The code says, in effect, `if (!op || !buildMode)`. Your statement after the code says `if (!(op || buildMode))`. Applying [DeMorgan's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) to that, the code should be `if (!op && !buildMode)`.

```
@EventHandler
public void blockBreakWithBuilder(BlockBreakEvent e)
{
    if (onWorld(e.getPlayer()) && !e.getPlayer().isOp() && !buildMode.hasBuildMode(e.getPlayer()))
    {
        e.getPlayer().sendMessage("True");
        e.setCancelled(blockBreak);
        return;
    }

    e.getPlayer().sendMessage("False");
}
```